# How do I scrape from my Selenium results using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a script that opens up a yahoo finance page, applies filters and clicks the "Find Stocks" button, then gathers the ticker names from the page. I've successfully used Selenium to apply the filters, but when I run "driver" through BeautifulSoup, it extracts the tickers from BEFORE the filters were applied. How do I instead scrape from the updated HTML code after the changes were made to the webdriver? Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=100")
#open filters
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/header/button").click()
#click small cap
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button[1]").click()
#clear volume text box
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/input").clear()
#1 mill volume
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/input").send_keys("1000000")
time.sleep(1)
#click "find stocks"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]").click()

bigsoup = bs(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
tickerhtml = bigsoup.tbody.find_all(class_ = "Fw(600) C($linkColor)")

for tickerraw in tickerhtml:
    print(tickerraw.string)
```

Also- less important, but if anyone could find a better way to reach the buttons to apply the filters than what I did, please let me know. I'm pretty new to webscraping so this was the only way I could figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def main(driver):
    driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/most-active?count=100')
    waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    try:
        waiter.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-reactid='24']"))
        ).click()
        waiter.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class^=Py]"))
        ).click()
        myinput = waiter.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class^=Fz]"))
        )
        myinput.clear()
        myinput.send_keys('1000000')
        waiter.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.Bgc\(\$linkColor\)"))
        ).click()

        target = [x.text for x in waiter.until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//table//td//a"))
        )]
        print(target)

    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    main(driver)
```

Output:

```
['HCMC', 'CBDL', 'HPIL', 'TXTM', 'NOHO', 'IDGC', 'UBQU', 'PZOO', 'DRNG', 'TGGI', 'INCT', 'RETC', 'WNBD', 'NSAV', 'ADGO', 'ITVI', 'EFIR', 'PRPM', 'FTXP', 'AMLH', 'TBEV', 'GNCP', 'NBRI', 'MSPC', 'KPAY', 'TGRO', 'FONU', 'GTEH', 'FTEG', 'NNRX', 'VNTH', 'FUTL', 'CWBR', 'TWOH', 'MDCN', 'GEGP', 'INND', 'MYDX', 'PUGE', 'NECA', 'PHIL', 'EEENF', 'ECEZ', 'COWI', 'BSSP', 'FCGD', 'AUNXF', 'PDGO', 'SEEK', 'BDGR', 'GRSO', 'DYAI', 'NUUU', 'KYNC', 'CLWD', 'IHSI', 'RSHN', 'ICNM', 'FHBC', 'FOYJ', 'PLYZ', 'LTNC', 'GARB', 'HESG', 'AMD', 'EEGI', 'RGBP', 'GMEV', 'ADTM', 'ORPH', 'HAON', 'INCC', 'PBYA', 'CYBL', 'BBRW', 'AZFL', 'AFOM', 'WWIO', 'JPEX', 'AMC', 'VIZC', 'LCLP', 'PSRU', 'PYCT', 'LATF', 'PRMO', 'SBES', 'TMGI', 'BAC', 'SNDL', 'DPLS', 'QBAN', 'ILST', 'XELA', 'BOTY', 'SGMD', 'MRNA', 'BRNE', 'MTVX', 
'WCVC']
```